# Retrofit. Response body is null

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I use retrofit 2.0.0 and GSON converter.

I have Response string

```
{"errors":["Incorrect unlock code"]}
```

I try convert it to object:

```
public class User {
    ArrayList<String> errors;
}
```

But in callback `response.body()` is null. For other objects, which don't contains arrays, only string and int fields, all is ok!

This is how i init retrofit:

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    client.interceptors().add(interceptor);

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://testurl.com")
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    service = retrofit.create(SignApi.class);
```

Comment: did you check what is the response you got in your browser ..

Comment: Yes, i check. I got right json string

Comment: can you post your SignApi class?

Comment: I find my error with Api class. Thanks for all

Comment: why didn't you post your answer?

Comment: I tried to cast response body. But error body contains errors.